# Android - proguard ignores -keep on Swig methods

Tags: android, jar, native, proguard, swig

I'm using proguard to obfuscate a (SDK) jar file I've created.

The SDK contains a Java Service, a statically compiled C++ lib and a SWIG (ver 2) interface via which the Service and the lib communicates.

I've added relevant '-keep' and '-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses' statements to the configuration file.

**But one file keeps getting (partially) obfuscated.**

The first part of the proguard config looks like this (all collected from the net):

```
-libraryjars '/Library/DevTools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar'
-libraryjars 'libs/android-support-v4.jar'
-libraryjars "libs/armeabi-v7a/libnativesdk.so"
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-injars bin/mysdklib.jar
-verbose
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

***My specific classes addition looks like this:***

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class com.company.MySdkIfJNI{
    private final static native void swig_module_init();
    public static *;    
    public final static native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class com.company.MySdkWrapper{
    public *;
}

-keep class com.company.IntWrapper

-keep class com.company.StatisticsParcel{
    public *;
}

-keep class com.company.JNILibCallbacks
```

All the classes I keep works fine. The problem is with the 'MySdkIfJNI' class.

This is an Swig (http://www.swig.org/) auto-generated interface between the native lib and the Java service.

I tried various configurations in order to keep this class as is but proguard keeps obfuscating it.

I tried '-keep' , '-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses', '-keepclasseswithmembernames'

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class com.company.MySdkIfJNI{
    private final static native void swig_module_init();
    public static *;    
    public final static native <methods>;
    *;
}
```

**both with arguments and without arguments**

But after proguard finishes (without any errors / warnings) I find out that only part of the methods has been obfuscated.

The native methods are kept, such as:

```
public final static native void JniMYSdkClient_setLogLevel(long jarg1, JniMYSdkClient jarg1_, int jarg2);
  public final static native void delete_JniMYSdkClient(long jarg1);
```

But all the Java methods that starts with SwigDirector are obfuscated, such as:

```
public static void SwigDirector_JNIMyCallbacks_onEvent(JNIMyCallbacks self, int accountId, int eventId, String sessionId, String msg) {
    self.onEvent(accountId, eventId, sessionId, msg);
  }
```

This obfuscation causes the Native swig interface to fail finding this callback methods and my lib crashes.

**Any ideas of how can I keep this specific class AS-IS ?**

Thanks in advance,
Or Pol.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I didn't find any solution to the particular *SWIG* methods but since the *SWIG* wrapping code is already really messy I have decided it doesn't have to be obfuscated with Proguard.

I **moved** the *SWIG* interface to an **external JAR** file and imported it as '**-libraryjars**'

Now the native layer finds this methods and everything works perfect.

Thanks anyway!

Best regards,
Or.

Comment: Can I get more details?

Answer (score 0):

Swig callbacks need to be keep from obfuscation. 
First try to keep all generated java files by swig and compile and see. Crash will fix. Like below

-keep com.custom.project** { *; }
-dontwarn com.custom.project**

Next maximize your files for obfuscation. 
Hope it helps.